# What's the connection between the word 'roam' and the cell phone roaming?

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

"Roam" is defined as "move about aimlessly or without any destination, often in search of food or employment".

**What does it have to do with the cell phone roaming? Why is roaming called that?**

> Roaming is a general term referring to the ability for a cellular
>   customer to automatically make and receive voice calls, send and
>   receive data, or access other services, including home data services,
>   when travelling outside the geographical coverage area of the home
>   network, by means of using a visited network.

Answer (score 10):

The mobile subscriber is unaware when they move from one telephone operator's region to another, so from the perspective of the telephone operators, they are indeed **roaming** aimlessly from region to region.

And the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=roam) for **roam**  suits that well

> possibly from Old English ramian "act of wandering about," which is probably related to aræman "arise, lift up."

The food/employment mentioned by OP is just an example used by one particular dictionary's *roam* definition.

**EDIT** : originally I answered describing subscribers moving from cell to cell which in GSM parlance is actually called [handover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handover) if it's during a call rather than roaming.

Comment: Just a slight unrelated technicality: a handover can occur at any time, not just during a call.

Comment: This description could apply to ordinary non-roaming just as well. In cell phone terms, roaming doesn't mean moving about from place to place; it's about being "away from home" (outside of the carrier's service area)

Answer (score 8):

As commented by FumbleFingers, *roam* is a synonym of *travel*.

The definition in [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/roam) should also help:

> to go to different places without having a particular purpose or plan

From the communication service provider's perspective, the notion of the subscriber wandering in geographical regions where their service is not *directly* available ("**different places**") must imply "**roaming**".

Further, as per [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ARoaming):

> The term "roaming" is actually ancient and does not originate from any
>   technology at all. Roaming barbarians have been mentioned by Egypt and
>   Roman historians already, roaming simply means the process of moving
>   around the countryside without regard for who the lords of the
>   individual strips of land are that are being passed through